# Sinatra with Rails reset session every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, sinatra

I have a rails web application and I need to create API for mobile clients. I choose a Sinatra web framework for this. But I have a problem with my Sinatra app, after every request all data session lost.
My API looks like this(lib/api/core.rb):

```
module Api
  class Core < Sinatra::Base
    set :session_secret, 'secret'
    enable :sessions

    get '/foo' do
      content_type :json
      session['foo'] = 'some value'
    end

    get '/bar' do
      content_type :json
      session['foo']#everytime is nil
    end

  end
end
```

In my route.rb I wrote this:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'api' do
  mount Api::Core => '/'
end
```

I use Rails 3.2.8, Sinatra 1.3.3

**And my questions is how can I store data between requests(it's need me for authentication) ?**

Comment: You're using both Rails and Sinatra?

Comment: Yes, Rails for my main web app, Sinatra for API

Answer (score 0):

Your APIs should be stateless. Authentication is usually done with tokens that are sent along with every request. See RailsCast [#352 Securing an API](http://railscasts.com/episodes/352-securing-an-api) for more info.

Comment: I know about token authentication and I will use it. But I need store user id for every token, because I will use it in my queries.

Comment: I am not sure that is the problem then. You have a stateless API, everytime you get a request, you find the user based on the token provided (User.find_by_token(params[:token]) and do stuff.